# Eclipse with Java wont display matching variables

Tags: java, eclipse

Hey guy, 
I haven't let this get to me till now. My Eclipse used to show me where I used other global and local variables when I clicked on one of them. It doesn't anymore. I looked at General>Appearance>Colors and Fonts. In the Java folder I find something that looks like what I want. It's the Colored Labels - match highlight. The description says: The background color used to highlight matches when colored labels in Java views are enabled. I looked for that in the Java> How that's so weird I can't find it again as I'm writing this message. Anyway I guess that's what I'm looking for. Enabling the colored labels in Java. Where is that?

Comment: try to toggle mark occurrence by pressing `ATL + SHIFT + O`

Comment: That should be what you need. Just one thing: did you click the "toggle mark occurrences" button in your toolbar (default shortcut is Sfift+Alt+O - letter O, not digit 0)

Comment: Man that was it thanks guys. I noticed I hit Shift+Ctrl+O to organize my imports and I have messed that up sometimes. I must have stopped messing up and with Sfift+Alt+O as I turned it off. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access to your variable location: you have to click on your variable and maintain the "ctrl" hitted.
for color: right click in your java class, go to "open with" then select java editor, if the color's problem persist go to Windows>preferences>Java>Editor ther click "restore default" or specify your editor, then click ok.
Hope that my intervention helps you.

Answer (score 2):

I tried `window -> preferences -> java -> editor -> mark occurrences ->` and selected all options.

Now it works.